# Sum a number of specific rows before and after

Tags: sas, sum, lag

[image: data]
I want to do a sum of 250 previous rows for each row, starting from the row 250th.

```
X= lag1(VWRETD)+ lag2(VWRETD)+ ... +lag250(VWRETD)

X = sum ( lag1(VWRETD), lag2(VWRETD), ... ,lag250(VWRETD) )
```

I try to use lag function, but it does not work for too many lags.

I also want to calculate sum of 250 next rows after each row.

Comment: If you want to do a sum of 250 previous rows, it should be starting from row 251th.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a moving sum both forwards and backwards where the sum is missing until that 250th observation. The easiest way to do this is with `PROC EXPAND`.

Sample data:

```
data have;
    do MKDate = '01JAN1993'd to '31DEC2000'd;
        VWRET = rand('uniform');
        output;
    end;

    format MKDate mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Code:

```
proc expand data=have out=want;
    id MKDate;

    convert VWRET = x_backwards_250 / transform=(movsum 250 trimleft 250);
    convert VWRET = x_forwards_250  / transform=(reverse movsum 250 trimleft 250 reverse);
run;
```

Here's what the transformation operations are doing:

- Creating a backwards moving sum of 250 observations, then setting the initial 250 to missing.
- Reversing `VWRET`, creating a moving sum of 250 observations, setting the initial 250 to missing, then reversing it again. This effectively creates a forward moving sum.

Comment: TRIMLEFT would avoid the use of the data setp?

Comment: Excellent find! It works! I updated my answer with this.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found this solution helpful, please be sure to mark it as solved so that others can find it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The key is how to read observations from previous and post rows. As for your `sum(n1, n2,...,nx)` function, you can replace it with iterative summation.
This example uses multiple set skill to achieve summing a variable from 25 previous and post rows:

```
data test;
  set sashelp.air nobs=nobs;

  if 25<_n_<nobs-25+1 then do;
    do i=_n_-25 to _n_-1;
      set sashelp.air(keep=air rename=air=pre_air) point=i;
      sum_pre=sum(sum_pre,pre_air);
    end;

    do j=_n_+1 to _n_+25;
      set sashelp.air(keep=air rename=air=post_air) point=j;
      sum_post=sum(sum_post,post_air);
    end;
  end;
  drop pre_air post_air;
run;
```

Only 26th to `nobs`-25th rows will be calculated, where `nobs` stands for number of observations of the setting data `sashelp.air`.

Multiple set may take long time when meeting big dataset, if you want to be more effective, you can use array and DOW-loop to instead multiple set skill:

```
data test;
  array _val_[1024]_temporary_;
  if _n_=1 then do i=1 by 1 until(eof);
    set sashelp.air end=eof;
    _val_[i]=air;
  end;

  set sashelp.air nobs=nobs;
  if 25<_n_<nobs-25+1 then do;
    do i=_n_-25 to _n_-1;
      sum_pre=sum(sum_pre,_val_[i]);
    end;

    do j=_n_+1 to _n_+25;
      sum_post=sum(sum_post,_val_[j]);
    end;
  end;
  drop i j;
run;
```

The weakness is you have to give a dimension number to array, it should be equal or great than `nobs`.

These skills are from a concept called "Table Look-Up", For SAS context, read "[Table Look-Up by Direct Addressing: Key-Indexing -- Bitmapping -- Hashing](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi26/p008-26.pdf)", Paul Dorfman, SUGI 26.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want use normal arithmetic with missing values becasue then the result is always a missing value. Use the SUM() function instead.

You don't need to spell out all of the lags.  Just keep a normal running sum but add the wrinkle of removing the last one in by subtraction.  So your equation only needs to reference the one lagged value.

Here is a simple example using running sum of 5 using SASHELP.CLASS data as an example:

```
%let n=5 ;

data step1;
  set sashelp.class(keep=name age);
  retain running_sum ;
  running_sum=sum(running_sum,age,-(sum(0,lag&n.(age))));
  if _n_ >= &n then want=running_sum;
run;
```

So the sum of the first 5 observations is 68.  But for the next observation the sum goes down to 66 since the age on the 6th observation is 2 less than the age on the first observation.

To calculate the other variable sort the dataset in descending order and use the same logic to make another variable.